# Image View в Swift

Tags: xcode, swift, mobile-development

Добрый день!
Подскажите пож, как менять изображение в этом оутлете по условию (или я так понимаю скрыть один, показать другой). Оутлеты назвал image1 и image2. Меняться они должны по условию на ввод количества символов в textField!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как я понимаю вы создали 2 картинки и хотите показывать только одну из них:

```
if (textField!.text.characters.count > 5) {
    image1.hidden = true
    image2.hidden = false
} else {
    image1.hidden = false
    image2.hidden = true
}
```

Можно обойтись одной image view:

```
if (textField!.text.characters.count > 5) { // эта строчка разная в зависимости от версии swift
    image1.image = UIImage(named:"imageX")
} else {
    image1.image = UIImage(named:"imageY")
}
```

Comment: Спасибо о компетентный программист! Работает!

Comment: @ИгорьИванов если работает принимайте ответ

Answer (score 1):

Привет! Пишу ответ для Swift 3.
 Создаешь 3 аутлета 2 для фоток, 1 для textField.
Потом создаешь - IBAction - Send Events - Editing Changed.
Как это сделать? - На текстовое поле нажимаешь правой кнопкой, появляются варианты - там в под Sent Events находишь editing Changed и около него плюсик тянешь на UIViewController.
Теперь, при любом изменении поля будет происходить событие.

Весь код прилагаю.

```
import UIKit
class ViewController: UIViewController { 
@IBOutlet var image1: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet var image2: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet var textField: UITextField!
@IBAction func textFieldEditingChanged(_ sender: Any) {
    let length = textField.text?.characters.count
    if length! > 5 {
        image1.isHidden = true
        image2.isHidden = false
    } else {
        image1.isHidden = false
        image2.isHidden = true
    }
}
}
```